# Need help understanding multiple linear regression results

Tags: regression, interpretation

I am conducting a study and wanted to fully understand what my results are indicating. To me, they are reading that when factoring Z, there is a statistically significant relationship between X and Y,

[image: Multiple linear regression picture here]

Is this the case or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: It's difficult to interpret your results from a redacted image. In any case, interpretation of statistical models isn't a programming question. I have voted to migrate your question to CrossValidated, our sister Stack Exchange site for statistical questions.

Comment: ok well thanks @AllanCameron i will try there

Comment: There is so much you have left out it is impossible to say anything. For one very simple example, what is the correlation matrix among the predictors? In any case this is a stats question, not an R question.

Comment: There is no indication whatsoever about a relationship between X and Y. The significant p-value for Z (which I wouldn't trust much anyway, see my answer) says *nothing* about any relationship between X and Y.)

Answer (score 3):

The p-value of the F-test is 0.1092. This means that the model is *not* significantly better than a model that only uses the mean of X and none of the explanatory variables. It therefore means that you have no evidence that any of your explanatory variables contributes anything to explaining your X.

Note that the more tests you run, the larger is the probability that one of the tests is significant without anything actually going on. You apparently run tests for five different explanatory variables, and one of them is significant at 5% level (though not with a particularly small p-value). One significant test out of five can easily happen by chance, therefore I (and many others) recommend to look at the overall F-test first, and to go on interpreting the individual variables tests *only* if the F-test is significant, which it isn't.

By the way, the adjusted R squared is very low at 2.4% and confirms the impression that the explanatory variables hardly explain anything of the variation of the X.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help and have a lovely week ahead!